# ng2 dragula set new index value after reorder

Tags: angular, ng2-dragula

I'm using ng2-dragula package for drag and drop features but once reorder the list items, unable to get the updated array index. Here the code what I'm trying.

**HTML**

```
      <ul [dragula]='"bag-items"' ([dragulaModel])="contactArray">
                  <li *ngFor="let field of contactArray" >
                    <label>{{field.role}}</label>
                 </li>
      </ul>
```

**JS**

```
import { DragulaService   } from "ng2-dragula";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-project',
  templateUrl: './edit-project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-project.component.css'],
  providers: [    
      DragulaService
  ]
})

export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private dragula:DragulaService) {
    for(let i =0; i<=this.contactArray.length; i++) {
        console.log(this.contactArray[i].index)
   }
}
```

}

when I try to console the **this.contactArray[i].index** after reordering the list. Not working properly.

```
Default order looks like this


A
B
C
D  

{ Value :   A, index: 1 } 
{ Value :   B, index: 2 } 
{ Value :   C, index: 3 } 
{ Value :   D, index: 4 }
```

Once I reorder, need to update new index like the below for API update,

```
D
B
C
A 

{ Value :   D, index: 1 } 
{ Value :   B, index: 2 } 
{ Value :   C, index: 3 } 
{ Value :   A, index: 4 }
```

**this.http.post(API_URL+'product/update', BodywithcontactArray);**

Any expert advice please.

Comment: I think ng2-Dragula just change the position of the object in the array. using Dragula, you can't change the object value if you want to do this you have to change every index manually.

Comment: @SnehaPawar it's not true. ng2-Dragula change order in array but you have a lot of Drake action, so you can change value after move element from one place into another. Some of drake action give you option to get element id, another give you references to whole array where you should find object but generally you have a lot of option to manipulate a data in array.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the respective value of the object

```
this.dragula.drop.subscribe(value => {
      // here you have to do swap index manually
console.log(value[0]);

console.log(value[1]);

console.log(value[2]);

console.log(value[3]);
});
```